# Nunit - Why single test with unique name is executing multiple times?

Tags: nunit

I have a test like

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase("Chrome", TestName = "One")]
    [TestCase("Firefox", TestName = "Two")]
    [TestCase("IE", TestName = "Three")]
    public void MyTest(string Browser)
    {
    .............
    }
```

I am calling this through programming as

```
    SimpleNameFilter filter = new SimpleNameFilter() { };
    Test = "SeleniumTests.Test.One";
    filter.Add(Test); 

    CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
    TestPackage testPackage = new  TestPackage(@"D:\Test.dll");
    RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
    remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
    TestResult result = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), filter, true, LoggingThreshold.All);
```

when i executed the above code, the test "one" is executing , but calling multiple time, can anybody tell why this is happening like this?

Thanks in advance,
Kishore.

Comment: What happens if you remove the name for each TestCase?

Comment: @ChrisMissal Do you mean to remove [Test] attribute?, if so it doesn't make any difference, the Test One is executing multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

First of in your case you don't need the first `[Test]`, since you already have `[TestCase(...)]`. Just remove the attribute and see if this is going to make a difference.
Second of all, I believe what happens is, the Test class - `One` (is what I think you called it) get's picked up and executes all the tests within it the class. For example `MyTest` will run 3 times (for each `TestCase`).

I hope I understood you correct.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitar Dimitrov for your response, Removing [Test] attribute doesn't make any difference, i got a solution by removing all the testcases and make each testcase as a single test, i.e [Test]MyTest_One(), [Test]MyTest_Two(),[Test]MyTest_Three(), but the thing is i am getting more tests , is this a valid approach?

Comment: @Kishorereddy `TestCase` is a way to run the same test multiple times (with different parameters), so basically you'd see it as one test repeated in your case 3 times. If you want to separate each test on it's own, the approach you're suggesting is not wrong, it fits your requirements. Just make sure you have a common setup and not much repeated code, since it might end up a maintenance problem.

Comment: I have a Test as
    
    [TestCase("IE",TestName="1")]
    Public Void A(string Browser)
    {
    }
I am calling this in a button click as
    Test = "SeleniumTests.Test.1";
    filter.Add(Test); 
    .......
    TestResult result = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), filter, true, LoggingThreshold.All);
if i clicked the button 1st time, the Test is executing once, for 2nd click executing twice and for 3nd click , 3 times........

It is working fine if i modified the Test as

    Public Void 1()
    {
    }
for 1st button click, 2nd click......the Test is executing only once[expected].

Comment: Can you please help to run the test as expected number of times using testcase.